# $RANDOM variable doesn't seem to change after output is piped

Tags: linux, zsh

Pretty self-explanatory, but the $RANDOM variable only changes when the output is not piped. Is this a bug in zsh or the result of my lack of understanding somewhere? Here is the result of my commands:

```
┌──(root㉿linux)-[~/scripts]
└─# echo $RANDOM                             
14103
                                                                                                                                                                      
┌──(root㉿linux)-[~/scripts]
└─# echo $RANDOM
30417
                                                                                                                                                                      
┌──(root㉿linux)-[~/scripts]
└─# echo $RANDOM
3090
                                                                                                                                                                      
┌──(root㉿linux)-[~/scripts]
└─# echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20
af5655b26ab87e81ef4f
                                                                                                                                                                      
┌──(root㉿linux)-[~/scripts]
└─# echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20
af5655b26ab87e81ef4f
                                                                                                                                                                      
┌──(root㉿linux)-[~/scripts]
└─# echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20
af5655b26ab87e81ef4f
```

Why is this happening? The same script in bash seems to work.

Comment: FYI, you can demonstrate this more simply with just `echo $RANDOM | cat`

Comment: From `zshparam(1)`: "The values of RANDOM form an intentionally-repeatable pseudo-random sequence; subshells that reference RANDOM will result in identical pseudo-random values unless the value of RANDOM is referenced or seeded in the parent shell in between subshell invocations."  The pipe is running in a subshell, so RANDOM is (intentionally) the same each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior in `zsh`. See this [mailing list archive](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2017/msg00587.html)

> from zshparam:
>
> RANDOM 
> A pseudo-random integer from 0 to 32767, newly generated each time this parameter is referenced.  The  random  number
> generator can be seeded by assigning a numeric value to RANDOM.
>
> The  values  of  RANDOM form an intentionally-repeatable pseudo-random
> sequence; subshells that reference RANDOM will
> result in identical pseudo-random values unless the value of RANDOM is referenced or seeded in the  parent  shell  in
> between subshell invocations.

You can solve this by simply accessing `$RANDOM` again before the piped command.

```
$ echo $RANDOM | cat
27008
$ echo $RANDOM | cat
27008
$ temp=$RANDOM
$ echo $RANDOM | cat
30572
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the intended result?

Comment: Access it again before the piped command to trigger it to change. I've updated the answer.